# Force disconnect TCP connection when server gone

Tags: java, http, jersey, tcp

My application performs a HTTP long-poll to another server in a loop using Jersey.  It relies on the server to return within 30 seconds.  The problem is that sometimes the server dies and is replaced by a different one at a different IP address.  This causes the last HTTP call to never return and never timeout, so the polling loop in my application is stuck until I reboot my application.

How can I force my application to either interrupt the HTTP call or to detect that the server is gone?  It is a Java application using a Jersey client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a read timeout, with HttpURLConnection.setReadTimeout().

Comment: Sorry, did you mean `HttpURLConnection.setReadTimeout()`?